How to find the variance of a biased estimator of variance of standard normal distributed random variable?
Let $Y_i$ be an independently and identically distributed standard normal random variable. Denote $S_1^2$ as estimator of $\text{Var}(Y_i)$. How to find the variance of the biased estimator $S_1^2$?
$$
S_1^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2
$$

What have you tried? If $Y_i\sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d., can you express the distribution of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$ in terms of $n$ and $\chi^2_k$ for some suitable $k$?  Note that $\chi^2_k$ has variance $2k$.
